# Extract Data (Sign On Date) that occured 9 days from today

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stumped on how to extract data from a SQL database 9 days prior to their anniversary date. I'd like to run the SQL statement on 1/1/2014, it would then produce all records where January 9th is the anniversary date. The year is irrelevant.

Comment: How is the anniversary date stored? Is it just MM/DD, or does it include year? If it includes year, will it be the year that they were hired or some other year?

Comment: It is stored MM/DD/YYYY. The records include any past year.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(CURDATE, INTERVAL 9 DAY)) = DAYOFYEAR(AnniversaryDate);
```

The `DAYOFYEAR` function converts the date to a number (1-366), while the `DATE_ADD` function is adding the required 9 days to the current day, to pull back records that match the `DAYOFYEAR` of the anniversary date.

Please note, in your question you ask to pull the record 9 days prior of the anniversary date (Jan 9), but 9 days prior would actually be December 31, not Jan 1. If you want it to pull for Jan 9 on Jan 1, modify the `INTERVAL 9 DAY` to `INTERVAL 8 DAY`